# HTML/CSS Image Positioning Issue

Tags: html, css, image, positioning

I am currently working on a project where I am trying to position an image within a div, but I do not want to div height which is set to 'auto' to expand when this image is placed so far I have got the following:

HTML:

```
<div id="LogoAndMenu">
<div class="Center">


    <div id="LogoIcon">
        <img style="    text-align:center;"src="images/logoicon.png" />
    </div> <!-- end div #LogoText-->

    <div id="LogoText">
        <img src="images/logotext.png" />
    </div> <!-- end div #LogoText-->


    <div id="Menu">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="Top" /> 
    </div> <!-- end div #Menu -->

</div><!-- end div #Center -->
```

CSS:

```
.Center{
margin:0px auto;
width: 1000px;
    text-align:left;
}

#LogoAndMenu{
    margin: 0; 
height:50px;
width: auto;
background: #e00b3b; 
text-align:center;
}

#LogoText{
float: left;
margin-top: 5px;
}

#LogoIcon{

float: left;
}

#Menu{
font-family:"Arial", Verdana, Serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 300;
color: #ffffff;
    }   

#Menu ul{
padding: 1.3% 0 1.3% 15%;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}

#Menu li { 
display: inline; 
}

#Menu li a{
padding: .2em 1em;
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
}

#Menu li a:hover{
font-weight: 700;
color: #ffffff;
background: #141515;
}
```

This works in Firefox and Chrome but I am having issues with Internet Explorer 8 would be grateful for some feedback on how to resolve this as it's leaving me baffled...

Link to site at current stage: [www.enbright.co.uk/trunk/](http://www.enbright.co.uk/trunk/20110211)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work in IE8 is that your page is being displayed in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

If you get rid of this line at the top of your document:

```
<!--<?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );?>-->
```

It'll look fine in IE.

To avoid problems like this in the future, remember that the doctype should always be the very first line.

Comment: By the way, PHP isn't being parsed on your page at all. For instance you have `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />`.

Comment: Line removed, doctype is now first line in file and your a genius I didnt realise a line commented out would affect it but I guess it does haha thanks buddy!

Comment: Yeah I know it is not at the moment, i am just templating a joomla template in html/css first thanks for the mention....

Comment: Yeah, this could easily drive you crazy and make you hate IE, until you know the trick.

Comment: Turning off Quirks mode is okay, but it relies on PHP, this is fine in your case, but if you wanted to use CSS check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077538/html-css-image-positioning-issue/5077669#answer-5077669) and [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/uxNZQ)

Comment: @Alex Thomas: Sorry to burst your bubble, but this doesn't rely on PHP in the slightest. All he had to do was remove a line which happened to contain unparsed PHP code inside a HTML comment. If his first line was `<!-- hello world -->`, the problem and answer would have been the same.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to set a background-image of 1px wide red on white, with the height you want on #LogoAndMenu eg:

```
#LogoAndMenu{
background:url(blackwhite.png) top left repeat-x; // your 1px x Npx image
height:40px //set to what you want
}
```

Coded it up here - http://jsfiddle.net/uxNZQ/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `overflow: hidden;` to `#LogoAndMenu`'s styles?

Comment: Just tried it, the height becomes corrected but the bottom half of the image gets cut off because the overflow is hidden...

Comment: Oops, sorry. Guess I didn't understand your question correctly.

Comment: hehe no worries thanks for attempting to answer much appreciated